# To write mathematica code for summation using a given data

Tags: summation, partitions, code

I am given a set like some terms from the partition of $20$:

$\{\{17, 3\}, \{13, 7\}, \{11, 3, 3, 3\}, \{7, 7, 3, 3\}, \{7, 5, 5, 3\}, \{5, 5, 
  5, 5\}\}$.

From the above data,

$20= \underline{1}*17+\underline{1}*3= \underline{1}*13+\underline{1}*7 =\underline{1}*11+\underline{3}*3 = \underline{2}*7+\underline{2}*3 = \underline{1}*7+\underline{2}*5+\underline{1}*3 = \underline{4}*5$

Now the above underlined numbers indicate the number of repetitions of each term appearing in the partition. I need to write those number of repetitions in the form of summation involving factorials:

Like for the above case, I need to represent the summation for the above partition as:

${T=\frac{1}{1!*1!}+\frac{1}{1!*1!}+\frac{1}{1!*3!}+\frac{1}{2!*2!}+\frac{1}{1!*2!}+\frac{1}{4!}}$

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
fn=Tr[1/Times @@@ (Tally[#][[All, 2]] & /@ #!)]&;

fn@{{17, 3}, {13, 7}, {11, 3, 3, 3}, {7, 7, 3, 3}, {7, 5, 5, 3}, {5, 5, 
  5, 5}}
```

> 71/24

Comment: Apparently the answer for the above question is 1 + 1 + 1/6 + 1/4 + 1/2 + 1/24 = 71/24.

Comment: @user75105 - you are correct. Misplaced paren., fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
ip = {{17, 3}, {13, 7}, {11, 3, 3, 3}, {7, 7, 3, 3}, {7, 5, 5, 3}, {5, 5, 5, 5}};

Total[Times @@ Values[1 / Factorial @ #] & /@ Counts /@ ip]
```

> ```
> 71/24
> ```

Also

```
Query[Total, Times @@ Values[1/Factorial @ #] &] @ Dataset[Counts /@ ip]
```

> ```
> 71/24
> ```

```
Dataset[Counts /@ ip][Total, Times @@ Values[1/Factorial @ #] &]
```

> ```
> 71/24
> ```